# Multi master replication in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Can someone guide me to do multi-master replication with PostgreSQL.

I have done master-slave replication but how do I get master-master replication.

I have tried  to use pg-pool-II but I couldn't find any good documentation for it.

Let me know what can I do to achieve master-master replication in PostgreSQL.
thanks.

Answer (score 13):

It's very difficult to make real multi-master replication on PostgreSQL. There was no good solutions. May be you don't really need master-master replication and there is a room for vertical scaling (better disk system, more CPUs, more memory).

But if you want to do this I'd recommend to have a look at [PostgreSQL-XC](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Postgres-XC), looks like it's stable now.

Answer (score 11):

As far as I know you need a third party solution like [Bucardo](http://bucardo.org/wiki/Bucardo) to perform a multi master replication in PostgreSQL.

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://justatheory.com/computers/databases/postgresql/bootstrap-bucardo-mulitmaster.html) for an example of configuring Bucardo and PostgreSQL for a multi master replication.